# USB Ports Not Working On ASUS P11C-M/4L Server Motherboard

Tags: usb, drivers, motherboard, usb-storage

None of the USB ports on my motherboard are working. I'm using the following components:

- Motherboard: ASUS P11C-M/4L
- Processor: Intel Xeon E-2126G
- RAM: Kingston 8GB Module - DDR4 2666MHz Server Premier (2 sticks)
- PSU: EVGA 450BT (450 watts)

I'm not sure if I need to install drivers, and I can't install any OS because none of my USB's work. I cannot boot from my CD drive because I can't use my USB keyboard to get into BIOS. I'm not sure if the entire USB is not working or it is just not providing power.

No, unfortunately I do not have a ps/2 connection. All I have are USBs, ethernet ports, and a VGA.

When the system boots up, it shows the ASUS logo in the center, "`System Initializing`" on one side and on the other side "`20`". I assume this means 20%, but it never boots farther than that. The Q-code gets stuck at "`A0`". Please keep in mind that I don't have an OS as I haven't been able to access BIOS to boot from an installer.

Comment: USB ports should work to get into the bios, this is not a driver issue, drivers are built into the bios/uefi. How old is this board? Where did you purchase it?

Comment: @Moab, I purchased the board in the last week from Newegg. It was one of the resellers listed on the ASUS website.

Comment: The motherboard has DDR4 so it has to be a recent Intel chipset.  If there is a USB problem there is either a setting that has been enabled to emulate a legacy feature set or that feature has been disabled (when it's required).  Windows 7+ has built-in support for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0.  Windows 7 does not support being installed from a USB 3 device unless a driver is provided.  Windows 8+ does not have this problem.  Does this motherboard have a PS/2 port by chance?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound ASUS P11C-M/4L has only USB for keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @AlwaysBeProgramming - Are you using the USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 ports?

Comment: @Ramhound, I have tried all of the ports and none work as I described in the question. I'm not sure if this board even has USB 2.0 ports, but if it does I tried them

Comment: In order to provide an answer to this question I must know if has USB 2.0 ports or not.  I could look myself, but this is information, that can easily be provided in the body of the question (I also don’t know what case you have).  Are you using the Front I/O or the Back panel I/O ports?

Comment: @Ramhound, after checking the manual, I see that the only USB 2.0 port is the one mounted directly on the motherboard and is not accessible unless the side panel of the case is off (it doesn't "stick out" of the case). It also says that it doesn't accept 1394 cables on this port.

Comment: @AlwaysBeProgramming - Why are you trying to use Firewire (1394) with a USB port?  You need to make sure you are NOT using the USB 3.1 Gen 2 ports with keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm not. I just provided that for your reference. I'm trying to use a standard USB keyboard.

Comment: I am completely confused the reason you would even mention Firewire, it is a given that a USB port, is not compatible with Firewire.  Please stick with relevant facts to your problem, unrelated factoids while interesting, will confuse people like myself.